# Получение данных из файла: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Требуется открыть файл и считать данные на python 3. Ну и как обычно возникает проблема с кодировкой.

```
with open('content.html', 'rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
print(text.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xab' in position 66
20: character maps to <undefined>
```

Открывал файл как в бинарном, так и в текстовом режиме с параметром encoding и без него. Как прочитать файл?

Comment: Может быть файл действительно не в UTF-8, а допустим в кодировке cp-1251?

Comment: notepad++ говорит, что utf-8 (без BOM)

Answer (score 2):

Кто-то из них врет.

Что определеннно, так это 66-ой байт  шестнадцатиричное `ab` **не может быть первым байтом символа** в кодировке UTF-8.

Посмотрите на байты перед 66-м.

Comment: Спасибо, перед 6620 символом были кавычки «, и питон их не пропускал.

Comment: Эти кавычки (не знаю как их набрать), как раз код 0xAB (открывающая) и 0xBB (закравающая) в **кодировке cp-1251**.