# Ошибка при запуске программы через консоль

Tags: python-3.x, консоль

Я написал программу и проверил через IDLE (там всё работает), но когда запускаю через консоль, то вылетает ошибка и мгновенно консоль исчезает, но я смог её сфотографировать, вот и она:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как исправить?

Comment: Добавьте код, так удобнее для всех.

Comment: И судя по ошибке проблемы с кодировкой. Вот похожие вопросы: [1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/151750/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-char) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092833/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters)